# How to do TDD with functional patterns

Tags: functional-programming, tdd

How do you tests functional patterns in TDD, or maybe better question is how do you drive your code by TDD to functional patterns?
For me it seems that all TDD movement is more in OOP side, but I wonder about good techniques for FP and TDD.

Comment: It us *unclear* why you think functional programming makes a fundamental difference to using TDD.

Answer (score 2):

1. Write a single failing test.
2. Write the simplest code that passes.
3. Refactor.

There's nothing in there about OOP, FP, or any other programming paradigm.